# post a form to a reactJS application and get the form data

Tags: reactjs

I work for a company that has a web site which was developed in ASP.net. Currently, one of our clients logs into our site by filling in a form on their web site and posting the form to us.  This is the code of their form:

```
<body>
    <form id="loginform" class="login-form" action="http://mycompany_site.com/loginpage.aspx " method="POST" name="frmLogin">
    <p>
        <label id="user_login_label" for="user_login">USER ID</label> <input id="user_login" name="user_id" type="input" /><br /><label id="user_pass_label" for="user_pass">PASSWORD</label> <input id="user_pass" name="password" type="password" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="wp-submit" type="submit" value="Sign In" />
    </p>
</body>
```

The page on my companies site (using visual basic) is coded like this to retrieve the two fields from the passed form:

```
Dim mqUserID As String = Request.Form("user_id") + "        "
Dim mqPassword As String = Request.Form("password") + "        "
```

We have developed a reactJS application which we would now like our client to post the form to instead of the current .aspx page.

What we would like to do is have my client change the url that they are posting to too be our reactJS application url.  To test this, I created an html page on my development machine and copied in my clients form.  Then I changed the url in the code to point to the endpoint supplied to me by AWS.  The code that I am executing looks like this:

```
<body>
    <form id="loginform" class="login-form" action="http://401kmobileapp.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ " method="POST" name="frmLogin">
    <p>
        <label id="user_login_label" for="user_login">USER ID</label> <input id="user_login" name="user_id" type="input" /><br /><label id="user_pass_label" for="user_pass">PASSWORD</label> <input id="user_pass" name="password" type="password" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="wp-submit" type="submit" value="Sign In" />
    </p>
</body>
```

When I run the html code on my development machine, and enter a user id and password and submit the form, I get this response:

```
405 Method Not Allowed
Code: MethodNotAllowed
Message: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
Method: POST
ResourceType: OBJECT
RequestId: 91DA10855CE577C9
HostId: I2e4xaKB1wSyTFfTVlz1LMdJCFNCqgF0abm3dtfFoyk/thNe01ewxbo+lV5aLf1Dtn5yEsib938=
```

If I enter the endpoint of the reactJS application into my browser and enter the user ID and password, I can successfully log into the system.

The reactJS application is designed to look for a querystring and use that data to log the user in automatically.  If no querystring is found, then the login page is rendered.

What code would be needed in the reactJS application to 1 - resolve the 405 error and 2 - retrieve the form data and log the user in automatically?

Comment: Are you asking how to get form data in React without getting it from the url?

Comment: I am able to get date from the url by using the code I provided but that will retrieve data if passed in the url, ie: https://example.com?user_id=xxxxx&password=yyyyy. I did not think data from a form was passed as a url parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In React a good way to handle forms is to use Controlled Components (inputs) whose state comes from the containing Component's state, and override the default form submit behavior.

Basically you store form data in a Component's state and then the form gets its data from the state (rather than holding the data itself). This makes it easer to access the form data when it's time to submit the form as you already have all of the date in state.

Then when the user submits the form, you prevent the default HTML submit action and implement your own using AJAX, passing the form data along.

For example:

```js
class LoginFormComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            userId: "",
            password: "",
        }
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        const {
            name: fieldName,
            value: fieldValue,
        } = event.target;
        this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, fieldName: fieldValue}));
    }

    handleSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default HTML form submit
        const { userId, password } = this.state;
        const loginURL = "https://example.com/login"
        const response = await fetch(loginURL, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({user_id: userId, password: password}),
        })
        // do something with the response (e.g. check if successful)
    }

    render() {
        const { userId, password } = this.state;

        return (
            <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
                <label>User Id</label>
                <input type="text" name="userId" value={ userId } onChange={ this.handleChange }/>

                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" value={ password } onChange={ this.handleChange }/>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: But doesn't your example render a form and then respond to the input?  I'm not looking to render a form.  My client has the form on his site and is just posting a form to a url on my server.  Maybe I am not understanding what you are trying to demonstrate. It is my understanding that the form will remove the parameters from the url and place them in the request body.  That is why in the current visual basic .net code, I we make use of the Requerst.Form and not Request.Querystring

Comment: I thought you are making an app in React that allows a user to login to the existing .NET server. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @JonathanSmall Or are you trying to have the client log into the React app from the existing site? If so, how do you pass the user off to React?

Comment: The login form is hosted on my clients web site.  They are currently posting that form to a specific url on my server (www.example.com/somepage.aspx).  The url they are posting to is a visual basic .net page. It makes use of the Request.Form command to extract the 2 form data fields that my client is passing.  I want to be able to have them post the form to a reactJS url instead of the .net url and then have reactJS be able to interrogate the form data and pull out the two fields that are being passed.

Comment: Okay so the user_id and password will be in the querystring of the React url? And you're looking to extract those parameters and then automatically pass them along to your server for authentication?

Comment: @JonathanSmall you also mentioned that your code works fine for getting data from the url query string, but that you did not think data from a form was sent via url. It depends whether the form submits using GET or POST as the method. Usually, if you're sending data to a server from a form, you would use POST and put the data in the Payload. But in this case since you're passing the data off to another site (the React site) you'll have to send the data using GET in the url query string.